# How to convert unix millis to NSDate on 32 bit iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to convert UNIX millis (returned from server) into NSDate using Swift. This is the returned data:

```
{
    timestamp: 1469263452058
}
```

It works perfectly on iPhone 5S and higher. But it failed on iPhone 5 because it's 32 bit.
I also tried to cast the value into Int64 and it crashed.

Please don't hardcode the 1469263452058. I need to store the timestamp into variable before I can convert it to NSTimeInterval.

Comment: How are you converting the time to `NSDate`?

Comment: Is the timestamp from the year 48529?

Comment: @pableiros no, please enter this site, and put the timestamp http://currentmillis.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to divide by 1000 the timestamp

For example:

**Swift 2**

```
let result = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonFromServer, options: [])

if let timestamp = result["timestamp"] as? Double {
    let timeInterval: NSTimeInterval  = timestamp/1000

    print("time interval is \(timeInterval)")
    //Convert to Date
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)

    //Date formatting
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd, MMMM yyyy HH:mm:a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    print("formatted date is =  \(dateString)")
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
let result = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonFromServer as Data, options: [])

if let timestamp = result["timestamp"] as? Double {
    let timeInterval: TimeInterval  = timestamp/1000

    print("time interval is \(timeInterval)")
    //Convert to Date
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)

    //Date formatting
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd, MMMM yyyy HH:mm:a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
    print("formatted date is =  \(dateString)")
}
```

Output:

```
time interval is 1469263452.058
formatted date is =  23, July 2016 08:44:AM
```

Comment: 1469263452058 is in the returned JSON data and is too big for 32bit data type to contain. In your example, the 1469263452058 is hardcoded, but when I fetch the data it need to be put in the variable first.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Have you tried to put the value on a Double?

Comment: NSTimeInterval or Double is 64 bit, but double's bit allocation is divided between exponent and and fraction. Therefore, it is not able to contain the timestamp. I need a way to store the timestamp before I can divide it with 1000.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony I have edited my answer and this is worked for me, I have tested on an iPhone 4S

Comment: @EdwardAnthony and I have tested on an iPhone 5

Comment: Holy cow! I works. In theory Double wouldn't be able to contain the number since it need the remaining bit for the fraction But it works.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I tried it in Playground.

```
let timestamp: Double = 1469263452058/1000
let timeWithNSDate = NSDate.init(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
```

Output:

`"Jul 23, 2016, 2:14 PM"`

Comment: In your example 1469263452058 is hardcoded. When I receive the data as JSON response from the server, I need to store the 1469263452058 into variable first, but it's too big for 32 bit data type to handle.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony you can use the above code while parsing the JSON. Just replace the hardcoded value with `json["timestamp"]`.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Since Float is a 32-bit data type, use the json value as float:  `let timestamp: Float = 1469263452058/1000` and then convert that to double. Like this: 
    `let tim: Double = Double(timestamp)`
Then just use the NSDate timeIntervalSince1970 method to get NSDate.

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried to cast it using as! Int64 and it crashed. Any idea?

Comment: @thegrandhi ok, trying now.

Comment: @thegrandhi I appreciate your answer it works, but I need to store the timestamp first as variable such as let `unixTimestamp = json["timestamp"]` and then divide it by 1000.

Comment: @LeoDabus it becomes a weird number such as 3477234, I'm pretty sure this is because NSNumber is 32 bit, since the result is same if I cast it to Int32. Anyway cast it to Double seems to work.